# Can the HDD in a Sony VAIO SB laptop be replaced with SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

I want to replace the HDD in my Sony VAIO SB laptop, but I'm not sure if it's even possible. I know that the ODD can be replaced with an SSD (via a caddy) so that's my alternative.

Are there any advice/tutorials on this matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to know may be to just take the hard drive out and look at it.  If the drive is a standard 2.5" drive, and has a normal SATA connector, then there is a good chance that a 2.5" SSD can be used as a drop in replacement.

It will look like the one in this image at the top:
[image: SATA and SAS connectors]